# Angular Material Drag and drop - Drag an element and on Drop it should convert to another element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have gone through the documentation of angular-material drag and drop. It mainly deals with a list of elements that can be dropped to another container which has a list.

I have a requirement where I will drag `span` element from the menu and it will convert to `img` in the dropped container. I can drop as many `span` elements to the same drop container. The span should be re-usable (not to cut-off from the menu list). Is this possible with Angular-material? Please suggest.

Comment: For example, if you have widget builder where we can drag form fields like text box, check box etc. These fields should be there in the source menu and should render like a text box where we have dropped the field.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview). You just need to use `img`-elements in your drop container and adjust the drop method. Look at this adjusted Angular Material Example

**component.ts**

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {

    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    console.log('Moved ' + event.container.data[event.previousIndex]);

  } else {

    const randomImageUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/seed/' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '/380/100';
    this.doneImageSources.push(randomImageUrl);
    console.log('Converted Item ' + event.item.data + ' to ' + randomImageUrl);

  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>To do</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="originItems"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list">

    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of originItems"
         cdkDrag
         [cdkDragData]="item">
      {{item}}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Done</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="doneImageSources"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

    <img *ngFor="let imgSrc of doneImageSources"
         [src]="imgSrc"
         class="example-box"
         alt="Random Image"
         cdkDrag>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wculyd

Hope this helps! :-)